# BASH: Count occurrences of each element from list A in list B

Tags: bash, count

Is there an efficient way to count the number of occurrences for each item of list A in list B? This question has been solved in different programming languages (e.g., C/C++, Java, Python) but I have not found the solution in BASH. My very naive idea is to use a nested `for` loop to solve it but I think there should be a better approach for this.

```
# input
listA=(1 2 3 4 5)
listB=(3 1 2 4 1 3 4 5 2 6 8 7 3 9 6 5 1 2)

# expected output
# 1: 3
# 2: 3
# 3: 3
# 4: 2
# 5: 2
```

Any comments/suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Why do you think there should be a better approach for this? `bash` doesn't have very powerful array operations.

Comment: That's just my guess. I am not comfortable with using `for` loop so I am seeking a better solution if any.

Comment: You could use something with `xargs -I grep {}` or with `sort | uniq -c | ... | grep -f` but both would be even less efficient as they would scan one of the list multiple times. The most efficient solution I can think of is an `awk` script with a dynamic array, but that isn't really a `bash` solution, isn't it. The approach with the dynamic array could also be done in bash, but then you would need a `for` loop again which is slow. To conclude: No, I don't think this can be done as efficient and beautiful as you imagine unless you use a non-standard tool specially made for tasks like this.

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: `c=(); for i in "${listB[@]}"; do ((c[$i]++)); done; for i in "${listA[@]}"; do echo "$i: ${c[$i]}"; done` should be O(B+A)

Comment: @jhnc Very nice answer!

Comment: When the elements of both lists consist of single characters, using standard utilities, this should give the output you expected: `tr -cd "${listA[*]}" <<< "${listB[*]}" | tr -s ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq -c | sed 's/.*\(.\).\(.\)/\2: \1/'`. I think you'd better be comfortable using `for` loops :) Also, the comment you liked used two `for` loops. And I wonder how you could solve this without using a `for` (or `while`) loop in `C`. Standard `C` library doesn't have list manipulation functions.  Well, you could use recursion but this wouldn't be an improvement over the iteration, for this task.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin I am sorry for the ambiguous issue when saying `for` loop since my very naive idea was using a nested loop to solve this issue and that's why I was seeking if there is a better solution that may or may not use `for` loop. If it does, it's still fine as long as it's not using the nested loop like @jhnc suggested. That's why I like his solution. (I also edited my question to avoid this issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say in comment you are not comfortable with using `for` loops, so here is a solution without them:

```
$ join -2 2 <(printf '%s\n' "${listA[@]}" | sort) \
            <(printf '%s\n' "${listB[@]}" | sort | uniq -c)
1 3
2 3
3 3
4 2
5 2
```

### Explanation

`<(...)` are Bash's process substitutions. `join` is given pseudo-files that actually correspond to the output of the commands.

`printf '%s\n' "${listA[@]}" | sort` sorts the element in `listA` and print them one by line.

`printf '%s\n' "${listB[@]}" | sort | uniq -c` does the same with `listB` but uses `uniq -c` to prefix each element with its number of occurrences.

`join` keeps the lines in this second output that matches a line in the first output.

Comment: Simple yet really nice solution in `bash` style.

Comment: @ThangM.Pham I guessed you were looking for something like that (stream oriented)... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

A solution in plain `bash` using an associative array, without using *nested* loops:

```
#!/bin/bash

listA=(1 2 3 4 5)
listB=(3 1 2 4 1 3 4 5 2 6 8 7 3 9 6 5 1 2)

declare -A freq # associative array to hold frequencies

for elem in "${listA[@]}"; do freq[$elem]=0; done

for elem in "${listB[@]}"; do [[ ${freq[$elem]} ]] && ((++freq[$elem])); done

for elem in "${listA[@]}"; do printf '%s: %d\n' "$elem" "${freq[$elem]}"; done
```

Notes:

- Elements are not restricted to integers nor single-character elements;
  script should work for any kind of element (including elements containing spaces, tabs, newlines... etc, except the null byte (`'\0'`), of course).
- Its efficiency depends on how associative arrays are implemented internally in `bash`.
- Associative arrays were introduced into `bash` with version 4.0.